# How many daily quests are stored internally?

Tags: hearthstone

I always thought when you reach the cap of 3 open daily quests, you receive one new quest once you clear one (provided you haven't received one that day because of the cap).

But today, when i hadn't cleared a quest for 2 days while at the limit (and having been in the game each day), i cleared 2 quests simultaneously and both were replaced. This rises questions.

- Since it's not just the one from that day, how many quests are stored internally ready to be received once there is enough space in the questlog?
- is this dependant on logging into the game on each respective day, putting the quest for that day in some kind of queue?
- is it dependant on clearing multiple quests simultaneously, meaning quests only reload once per day the first time at least one quest is cleared (assuming there are enough quests in queue)?
- if the answer to the previous question is yes, does this empty the queue or does it keep accumulating quests to be received?

As an example where the last point matters, let's say i have 4 quests in queue, then clear 2 simultaneously. The next day, I clear 2 quests simultaneously again. If the queue resets, only one new quest will be received.

Comment: I think the idea that the non-active quests are 'stored' is probably wrong. The answer could be infinite if blizzard simply stores a number of quests for which you are eligible and only generates the quests themselves when you have an open quest slot.

Comment: Agreed, i don't really care about technical details or terminology though. What I'm interested in is if the answer actually is infinite. They could do all sorts of things, the question is what do they in fact do?

Comment: Some testing was done and apparently, dropping a quest clears the queue.

Comment: As per [this duplicate question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/245108/what-is-the-rule-of-how-many-new-quests-you-get-at-one-day-in-hearthstone-4-x#comment338331_245108), the current version of Hearthstone uses a different set of rules than the accepted answer.  A new (or updated) answer is required.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This question unfortunately has now a quick and sad ending.

As of Patch 1.0.0.5170, according to the [Patch Notes](http://www.hearthpwn.com/news/436-hearthstone-patch-5170-new-quests-mobile-additions):

> Completing a quest when there are three quests in the quest log will no longer immediately grant a new quest.

What this means, in effect, is that 0 quests are stored internally, either directly or through a counter. If 3 quests are in your quest log and you log in, you will not receive a new daily quest. If you clear a quest afterwards, you will not receive the missed quest either.

---

*Currently (end of November, 2015), there is a [bug](https://twitter.com/bdbrode/status/667049642484363264) that appears whenever you don't re-roll any quests. It allows up to 3 quests to be stored in a hidden counter. See [Sorean's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/245414/68585) for more details on this behavior. **Note that this has been officially acknowledged to be a bug and will be fixed in the future!***

Comment: This answer is no longer accurate and needs an update as of 2015.  I had 3 quests stacked up for 3+ days.  Cleared all 3 yesterday.  This morning, when I thought I should have had 1 new one, I instead got 3 new quests, so at some point they returned the internal stacking (you just don't get them immediately).  Anyone know how this is working?

Comment: @DiabloMonkey are you sure? The answer below states the same, yet when I tested it back then, it didn't work. I'll happily change it, but I'd like more confirmation.

Comment: This answer is not valid anymore, since it is possible to get more than one new quest at a day, if the quest log has been full and more than one quests were complete the day before.

Comment: @Rob: Do you have a source for that? Feel free to edit it in if you do.

Comment: I just have the very same question, but no answer. But I know that your answer is outdated, because it just happened to me, to get more than one new quest the next day, after I finished all 3 quests. Unfortunately I don't have a source or a proof for it. Screenshots doesn't proof anything and a video has to be very long to be of some value. Unfortunately, I am not allowed to ask the same question again. I tried and it was deleted as duplicate.

Answer (score 12):

In the current state of the game you actually have 6 quest slots if you do not reroll any of your quests. 3 active ones that you can see and 3 that are hidden in a buffer.

What that means is that if you have 3 full quests and let 2 days go by the next time you play you will have 5 quests. 3 live and 2 hidden. If you complete 2 of your quests and then log in the next day you'll have 3 full quests again and one hidden (2 from the buffer and 1 from the next day).

Not rerolling the quests you have is the key factor. If you do it will reset your counter and you will only have the quests in your log.

[It is currently a bug that they do plan on fixing in the future](https://twitter.com/bdbrode/status/667049642484363264).

Answer (score 1):

As the poster above said, you don't get new quests anymore once you complete one on the same day, however, this is what happened to me:

I had my 3 dailies stacked already, and because of internet issues I couldn't play for 2 days, so when I played back, I did my 3 stacked dailies on one day, and the next day I logged in, I had 3 daily quests again, which probably means you can stack more than one quest after you already have three available, the only question would be the number of quests you can stack over those 3.

Comment: This might be better as a comment on the answer in question rather than a separate answer altogether.

Comment: I recently tried this and it didn't work.

Comment: For me it works just like alek describes it.