# What is the rule of how many new quests you get at one day in Hearthstone 4.X?

Tags: hearthstone

I was always eager not to have 3 quests at the end of a day, because I didn't want to miss the quest for the next day. Now I was on vacation and didn't play for several days. When I returned I completed all 3 quests at one day and the next day I got 3 new quests. Again, I completed them and I got 2 new quests on the next day.

What is the rule behind in the current Hearthstone version 4.X ? Can you actually miss quests if your quest log is full? Or is there an internal queue or something?

The question was already asked in 2014 for Hearthstone 1.X here: [How many daily quests are stored internally?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/161935/how-many-daily-quests-are-stored-internally)
The answer does not apply to the current version, unfortunately.

Comment: @Studoku Then how do I direct the attention of people to the old question? Just wait until somebody posts another answer to that question? Cannot be a solution in my opinion... The major version number changed 3 times since the old question was answered.

Comment: Since you have 75 reputation, you can offer a bounty on the old question. This will bump it and offer an extra incentive for people to answer it.

Comment: If you want to suggest a change of policy, post in Meta.

Comment: Well, I could do this. What about people with less than 75 reputation? But you are right, it's a topic itself for the meta --> http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11085/how-to-get-an-up-to-date-answer-for-old-questions-with-obsolete-answeres Instead I changed the question a bit, so that it is a Hearthstone 4.X specific one now.

Comment: You can't play the older versions of Hearthstone,so there's no point in asking about a specific version.

Comment: @Frank Version 4.X is the current version. I just added the version number in order to make clear, that my question requires a different answer than the one to the question about the old version.

Comment: Yes, but that plays no bearing on our curation; for all intents and purposes, Hearthstone can only be played as the latest version, so denoting a specific version doesn't really do anything. Your question is still a duplicate.

Comment: There is a point asking for a specific version. You ask for version 1, you get an answer (valid at that point). They change the rules in version 4, the accepted answer on the original question will not be changed (who would actually monitor versions in order to change their answers?). So the original answer is invalid. I see this as another question. Is actually quite easy to see if you expand to extreme: Consider you ask a question about GTA1. Then I come and ask a question about GTA5. From a specific point of view GTA 5 is just another version of GTA 1. So, my question would not be valid?

Comment: GTA1 and GTA5 is a completely different comparison. It would be more like GTA1 and GTA1 + patch

Comment: @Frank Yes, you are right, my question is still a duplicate. But I don't see another possibility to get it answered, since nobody would notice if I edited the old questions/answers as suggested in the policy. Only the original others and people searching for the answer to the same question would notice and probably none of them knows the answer. There must be a way to direct the attention of people who didn't get in touch with the question before to the question; besides putting expensive bounties.

Comment: That is unfortunately a failing of the SE network; it doesn't really handle out of date answers very well. What we've typically done is rely on more established users to provide the incentive to garner more up to date answers. It's not perfect, but its the best we have. Since you have the rep to bounty it, that's generally what we expect you to do.

Comment: @Studoku The OP has 179 reputation and the minimum bounty is 50.  It's not reasonable to ask someone to pay 28% of their reputation to essentially post a question.

Comment: @MikeR I agree, but rules are rules. If you want to help change those rules, [here's the discussion in meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11085/how-to-get-an-up-to-date-answer-for-old-questions-with-obsolete-answers).